# Pigeonhole principle problem 4

Tags: combinatorics

If we select $1001$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,…,2000\}$ there will be two numbers selected such that one divides the other. We need to prove this fact by noting that every number in the given set can be expressed in the form $2^k⋅m$ where m is an odd number and using the pigeonhole principle. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a good hint.  To add a little to it, how many possibilities are there for $m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only $1000$ possibilities for what $m$ can be, so if you select $1001$ numbers, among them will be two numbers $2^k m$ and $2^{k'} m'$ such that $m=m'$. Can you conclude from here?